# Is there a way for <p> elements to not end in a break in HTML?

Tags: html

So, is there any way for `<p>` elements to not end in a break? You could add them together, like this:

```
<p id="id1">content 1 content 2 </p>
```

But can how can you keep an the `id` for the `<p>` element and not end in a break? Is there CSS for that or is it just impossible for `<p>` elements?
Code:

```
<p id="id1">I like to eat </p>
<p id="id2">Icecream and pickles </p>
<p id="id3">with cucumbers on top </p>
```

Desired result:

```
I like to eat Icecream and pickles with cucumbers on top
```

Actual result:

```
I like to eat
Icecream and pickles
with cucumbers on top
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p` is a block element by default, which means it takes up an entire horizontal row. One option would be to use `span` which is inline by default, or another option is to use css to make the `p` `display:inline`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it is. You can use Css display inline

```html
<p id="id1" style="display: inline">I like to eat</p>
<p id="id2" style="display: inline">Icecream and pickles </p>
<p id="id3" style="display: inline">with cucumbers on top </p>
```

**OR**

This is also another way of doing. and I would prefer this way as it is more clean.

```html
<style type="text/css">
  #id1,
  #id2,
  #id3 {
    display: inline;
  }
</style>


<p id="id1">I like to eat </p>
<p id="id2">Icecream and pickles </p>
<p id="id3">with cucumbers on top </p>
```

The Css Inline - Displays an element as an inline element (like ). Any height and width properties will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#test1 p {
  float: left;
}

#test2 p {
  display: inline-block;
}

#test3 {
  display: table;
}

#test3 p {
  display: table-cell;
}

hr {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<h2> Use float </h2>

<div id="test1">
  <p>I like to eat </p>
  <p>Icecream and pickles </p>
  <p>with cucumbers on top </p>
</div>

<hr/>

<h2> Use display:inline-block </h2>

<div id="test2">
  <p>I like to eat </p>
  <p>Icecream and pickles </p>
  <p>with cucumbers on top </p>
</div>

<hr/>

<h2> Use display:table </h2>

<div id="test3">
  <p>I like to eat </p>
  <p>Icecream and pickles </p>
  <p>with cucumbers on top </p>
</div>

<hr/>
```